# Pixelate animation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to pixelate an animation.. I have a .png image where I cut in frames. I have a scrollbar who gives a number, which is the new size of every pixel. (rasterSize)
I already did it for an image and it's working.
http://bht-homework.com/RMA/PIX_PRES1/

But for animation it looks like doesn't calculate the first pixels.
http://bht-homework.com/RMA/PIX_PRES2/

```
           var imgData=context.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);// width is 190,height 240
            for (var x = 0; x < spriteSizeWidth; x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < spriteSizeHeight; y++) {
                
                     var rasterX = ((x / rasterSize) | 0) * rasterSize;
                     var rasterY = ((y / rasterSize) | 0) * rasterSize;

                     var rasterValIndex = (rasterX + rasterY * imgData.width) * 4;

                     r=imgData.data[rasterValIndex];
                     g=imgData.data[rasterValIndex + 1];
                     b=imgData.data[rasterValIndex + 2];
                     a=imgData.data[rasterValIndex + 3];
               
                
                    context.fillStyle="rgba(" +r+","+g+","+b+","+a+")";
                    context.fillRect(x,y,rasterSize,rasterSize);
                }
          }
```

Does someone has an idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though it might look as it would skip the first few pixels of your image, it actually just draws the blocks at the wrong position. It's offset by `rasterSize`.

You need to shift back the pixels to the correct position.

So simply replace

```
context.fillRect(x, y, rasterSize, rasterSize);
```

by

```
context.fillRect(x - rasterSize, y - rasterSize, rasterSize, rasterSize);
```